Why is the output of the thermistor connected to the inverting terminal of the op-amp in this Texas Instrument IR thermometer schematic?
I am making an IR contactless thermometer by following this application note provided by Texas Instruments.
I have some doubts about a few connections in the schematic diagram provided.

Vref1 is connected to the inverting terminal of op-amp U3A, causing the output of the op-amp to shift as the ambient temperature changes. The value of Vref1 decreases as the temperature increases since it uses an NTC thermistor.
Why do we need to connect Vref1 to the inverting terminal of the op-amp? The algorithms provided suggest measuring the thermopile voltage and thermistor voltage separately, then calculating the room temperature using the thermistor value. The algorithm then compensates the temperature value to give an accurate object temperature. Can somebody help me with this?
Here is the link to the source code and algorithm.
Source Code
Algorithm

Looks like an approximate solution that ignores the 2nd order effect of nonlinearity on the sensor temperature offset.
The sensitivity compensation is via modifying the ADC Vref with the NTC temperature (increasing temperature decreases the reference so it compensates for the ~-0.5%/K coefficient.
The TP voltage is a nonlinear function of the TP temperature and the measured object temperature. But to a first order, the effect of sensor temperature is just a linear shift- the TP voltage goes down as the sensor temperature goes up, like any thermocouple device. So you want to shift the voltage up to compensate, hence the decreasing voltage connected to the inverting input.

Using an equation and inverse equation or LUT and reverse LUT is the ideal way to do it, but this is simpler.
